# I have a Fiktionsbescheinigung and want to travel to Indonesia to visit family. Will my Fiktionsbescheinigung allow me to travel?

Tags: visas, germany, paperwork

I am going to travel to Indonesia this weekend to visit family and have a Fiktionsbescheinigung. I am worried that this won't be enough for me to travel out of the country or even come back. Will I be fined for having a Fiktionsbescheinigung to travel?

Comment: https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/fiktionsbescheinigung#travel-with-a-fiktionsbescheinigung